# How to return Task<Object> using continuation on a child task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I like to minimize the scheduling of tasks that wait on eachother but not show it's one
How would I alter my TestOption1 to return a Task the the calling method?

[image: Task continuations]

```
    [TestClass()]
    public class SqlServerTests
    {
        public const string Membership = "Data Source=LocalHost;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=True;";

        [TestMethod()]
        public async Task ContinueWithTest()
        {
            using CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            //warm up so pooling is enabled on all 3 methods
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(Membership))
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "set nocount on";

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            var sw2 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            await TestOption2(cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            sw2.Stop();

            //allow the benefit of the doubt for the slower and give it cashed plans
            var sw3 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            await TestOption3(cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            sw3.Stop();

            Assert.IsTrue(sw2.ElapsedTicks < sw3.ElapsedTicks, "Stopwatch 2 {0} Stopwatch 3 {1}", sw2, sw3);


            var sw1 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            await TestOption1(cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            sw1.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"TestOption1: No internal awaits {sw1.ElapsedTicks:N0} ticks");
            Console.WriteLine($"TestOption2: 1x internal await {sw2.ElapsedTicks:N0} ticks");
            Console.WriteLine($"TestOption3: 2x internal await {sw3.ElapsedTicks:N0} ticks");

            Assert.IsTrue(sw1.ElapsedTicks < sw2.ElapsedTicks, "Stopwatch 1 {0} Stopwatch 2 {1}", sw1, sw2);
            Assert.IsTrue(sw1.ElapsedTicks < sw3.ElapsedTicks, "Stopwatch 1 {0} Stopwatch 3 {1}", sw1, sw3);
        }

        private static Task TestOption1(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(Membership))
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "set nocount on";

                return con.OpenAsync(cancellationToken)//fails as it does not wait for the db to open....
                      .ContinueWith((t) => cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                                        , cancellationToken
                                        , continuationOptions: TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously
                                        , scheduler: TaskScheduler.Default);
            }
        }

        private static async Task TestOption2(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(Membership))
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "set nocount on";

                await con.OpenAsync(cancellationToken)
                      .ContinueWith((_) => cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }

        private static async Task TestOption3(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(Membership))
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "set nocount on";

                await con.OpenAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to be able to do something like this

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestContinueWithDelegate()
    {
        var data = await TestOptionReturn().ConfigureAwait(false);
        Assert.IsNotNull(data);
    }

    private static Task<object> TestOptionReturn(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(Membership))
        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "Test1";

            return con.OpenAsync(cancellationToken)//fails as it does not wait for the db to open....
                  .ContinueWith(delegate { return cmd.ExecuteScalar(); }
                                    , cancellationToken
                                    , continuationOptions: TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously
                                    , scheduler: TaskScheduler.Default);
        }
    }
```

The following tests fail as the database doesn't open
[image]

[TestMethod]
        public async Task TestContinueWithDelegate()
        {
            using CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var data = await TestOptioDDL(cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            using var reader = await TestOptionOutput(cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            Assert.IsNotNull(data);
            Assert.IsTrue(reader.Read());
        }

```
        private static Task<object> TestOptioDDL(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(Membership))
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "TestOutput";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Data", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime) { IsNullable = true, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output });
                return con.OpenAsync(cancellationToken)//fails as it does not wait for the db to open....
                      .ContinueWith(delegate
                      {
                          cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                          return cmd.Parameters[0].Value;
                      }
                      , cancellationToken
                      , continuationOptions: TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously
                      , scheduler: TaskScheduler.Default);
            }
        }

        private static Task<SqlDataReader> TestOptionOutput(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(Membership))
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from sys.databases";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Data", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime) { IsNullable = true, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output });
                return con.OpenAsync(cancellationToken)//fails as it does not wait for the db to open....
                      .ContinueWith(delegate
                      {
                          return cmd.ExecuteReader();
                      }
                      , cancellationToken
                      , continuationOptions: TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously
                      , scheduler: TaskScheduler.Default);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you describe more about what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: If you are already sure that your connection works in synchronous mode, try this: `var t1=con.OpenAsync(cancellationToken); t1.ContinueWith(delegate
                      {
                          return cmd.ExecuteReader();
                      }
                      , cancellationToken
                      , continuationOptions: TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously
                      , scheduler: TaskScheduler.Default); return t1;` does this solve your problem?

Comment: @SinaHoseinkhani, nope, same error

Answer (score 3):

`TestOption3` is the best choice. Optimize for maintainability, not for saving a few milliseconds on what will be a highly I/O-bound task.

That said, your connection is closed because your connection is being disposed [before the tasks complete](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) (possibly before it's even opened!). If you're going to remove `async` and `await`, then you need to handle rewriting your method so that the disposal at the end of the `using` will be run *after* the tasks complete.

Comment: @Stehen  could you blog a sample, I'm sure there are quite a few developers looking for this. most of my tasks are quite fast and the async switching becomes an issue specially when the load on the sever get's larger

Comment: I'm curious to know how you concluded it was the async switching that was the problem? Note that your existing test timings aren't valid; `TestOption1` isn't actually running the command since the connection is closed.

Comment: the test 1-3 are over simplified so that all could try to execute it, when running 1 production code we use option 1 when we do insert, update and deletes and do not need a transaction, lot's of logging of non- critical data, change this to something slower and it really hurts